# Does set<vector<int> > have to define compare function?

Tags: c++, vector, set

I want to remove all duplicate elements in `vector<vector<int> >` so I used `set<vector<int> >`.

From the definition of set:

```
template < class T,                    // set::key_type/value_type
       class Compare = less<T>,        // set::key_compare/value_compare
       class Alloc = allocator<T>      // set::allocator_type
       > class set;
```

I think I should define a Compare class to compare `vector<int>` since there is no '<', '>' or '==' for `vector<int>`.

However, I wrote code in xCode as follow and it has been compiled correctly:

```
vector<vector<int> > res = permute(num); //num = {1,1,2}, res gets its permutation but has duplicates 
set<vector<int> > s(res.begin(), res.end()); //remove all duplicates
res.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Luckily, the `res` is returned with a lexicographical order without any duplicates, which is exactly what I want.

I'm just wondering how this works since I never define a compare function for vector. I looked up the manual book and didn't find something can answer my question. Could anyone give me some hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What makes you think [`std::vector` has no comparison operators?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp)

Comment: @juanchopanza dang, you beat me to it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on an invalid assumption that can be quickly disproved by searching the documentation.

Comment: How does that make it "off topic", of all things?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I really don't think that makes a question off-topic. The asker clearly didn't manage to find the right information, which we are able to provide in an answer. Voted to reopen.

Comment: My bad, didn't see the relational operator entry in vector reference page. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::less<T>` will just invoke `operator<` on the `T` objects, unless it is specialized. `std::vector` has [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) defined, which gives a lexicographic comparison of the elements.